# ¿Como cambiar URL Subversión Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, svn, subversion

Vengo trabajando con la URL (url1) en un proyecto Android en Android Studio, y por algún motivo decidieron cambiar la URL a (url2).

Intento hacer el relocate

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me aparece este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito de su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final no pude realizarlo desde el mismo Android Studio, pero después de buscar alternativas encontré una solución, apta para todo proyecto descargado SVN

**seleccionan la carpeta donde esta su proyecto**

en mi caso uso  TortoiseSVN

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y solo cambian la url

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

eso es todo..

vuelven a abrir su proyecto desde Android Studio y ya estaría apuntando a la nueva URL